# Why does the solution to dyld_decache segfault work?

Tags: ios, caching, segmentation-fault, jailbreak, dyld

Background: https://github.com/kennytm/Miscellaneous/issues/1

Take a special look at planetbeing's comment. But they're still confusing me:

1. "When read by processes running on iOS that have ASLR enabled, /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv7 appears changed due to the ASLR being applied, despite not actually being changed on the filesystem". According to my tests, md5 of /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armvXX changes at times, so seems this file IS BEING CHANGED on the filesystem. Am I misunderstanding anything?
2. If this file isn't changed on the filesystem, and a program(e.g. https://gist.github.com/theiostream/4366719) without PIC copies it to another location, both 2 files should be the same on the filesystem. When I scp them to my MAC, why can't the original file but the new copied file be decached?

Comment: How do you know the file is changing on disk?  Do you continually run an `md5 /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv7` command at a terminal?  And, it looks like copying the cache and then transferring it to your Mac is one of the recommended strategies ... is there a problem with that?  Or are you just trying to understand **why** it's necessary?

Comment: @Nate At first I've noticed the md5 changing using iFile, but I've written a simple command line tool to calculate the md5 of a specified file. The output is [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/st2sg). Notice the last 3 lines, the md5 has changed, but I don't know why. And there's a problem with copying the cache and scping it to my MAC, see my 2nd question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

dyld_shared_cache_armvXX is not changing in filesystem. Did simple test. Copied the file to my PC, checked MD5 with iFile on device itself. After reboot did it again. MD5 in iFile was indeed different but MD5 of the files on my PC was the same.

I quess it's due to how this file is treated by iOS. On application launch this file is being mapped into the app's address space so dyld don't need to lookup, open and read every library thus reducing application launch time. Because ASLR is enabled when app launches libraries are being placed at random offsets in it's virtual memory space (I don't think OS is changing something in the actual physical memory, offsets are added to virtual addresses). That's why you get different MD5 when ASLR enabled and the same MD5 when ASLR disabled.

Comment: "MD5 in iFile was indeed different but MD5 of the files on my PC was the same", doesn't that mean the cache **IS** changing in iOS filesystem? And of course it won't change once it's not under /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/ (because it's not an executable?).

Comment: I kinda know what your talking about, but my question is, if dyld_shared_cache_armvXX isn't decachable when scped from its original path due to ASLR, who's in charge of the segfault? sshd? But if it's copied to another place with a no-pic program, scp works well with dyld_decache, so I think it's not sshd's fault. My guess is that /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armvXX is changing during scping, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @snakeninny, look at the last modification date of dyld_shared_cache_armvXX - file is not being changed. Did another test. Copied dyld_shared_cache_armvXX to another place in iOS filesystem, checked MD5 with iFile and compared with MD5 of the same file on my PC. It was the same. dyld_shared_cache_armvXX is very special file because ASLR changes it's contents when it's being mapped into application's address space at launch. The file only APPEARS to be changed because changes only happen in memory without affecting original file on the disk.

Comment: If it's not changed, why would the md5 of /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armvXX change?  Look at [here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/st2sg). And isn't sshd reading from disk rather than from memory when I scp?

Comment: Files by default read from memory. When you read something the kernel is prefetching some parts of the file in memory cache. You are reading from this cache not from the disk itself. dyld_shared_cache_armvXX is a special file because it's being mapped into every application at launch. Then ASLR kicks in and offsets some parts of it in memory. When you read this file yourself you are actually reading file that's already been mapped and changed. Kernel is probably reusing what's already been mapped into application address space. This is why md5 is different from the actual file in filesystem.

Comment: So you mean dyld_shared_cache_armvXX in memory is different from its origin on disk, right? Just took a second look, sshd doesn't have PIE flag. Because both sshd and the other program disable ASLR, and read from memory, why is a file scped from the original dyld_shared_cache_armvXX undecachable, but a file copied to another location in iOS filesystem via the other program decachable? Aren't they both supposed to be undecachable because dyld_shared_cache_armvXX is changed in memory?

Comment: 1. Yes. All ASLR work is done in memory only. 2. When you copy a file to another location you get different file. OS doesn't care about their contents. If they are located in different paths they are different files. iOS obviously doesn't treat copied file any different - it's just a regular file. So you can open and read it without ASLR changing it's contents in memory. That's why it's decachable.

Comment: I'm still in question with the 2nd answer. Both sshd and the other program copies the file without PIE flag, why can the latter be decached not the former?